# SQL 2k8 reporting services authentication through DMZ

Tags: sql-server, authentication, reporting-services

I have SQL 2k8 server and reporting services installed on a server inside a domain. I also have a webserver that is outside the domain. I'm trying to run a reporting services report from the webserver (either through a URL or the report viewer component).

I have managed to authenticate (as detailed in 
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63882/how-do-you-view-sql-server-2005-reporting-services-reports-from-reportviewer-cont)
), and now the report kind of runs; the reporting service website loads with the 'run report' button and the parameters bar etc, however the report itself doesn't show, and all the images associated with the report web-page (e.g. arrows for 'next' and 'back' and things) don't load. I'm guessing this is because everything points to resources inside the domain, which are unavailable from outside?

To summarise, my question can be stated: how do I run a SQL reporting services report hosted on a machine in a domain, from outside the domain?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this certainly is possible. So something must be not quite right.

If you access the ReportServer.aspx page directly, and supply arguments in the form of a get-request, then you'll get a very spartan looking appearance. Could you clarify the circumstance when you're seeing this barren report? Is it when you use a direct-url, or through the report viewer?